# Replace element within a list of lists with MemberQ condition

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, conditional

I'm trying to replace the second element within a list of ordered pairs depending on whether that ordered pair exists within another set.

```
shortlist = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 1, 2}], 1]
sublist = {{0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}}
```

I want to do something like this

```
shortlist //. x_ /; !MemberQ[sublist, x] -> {x[[1]], 0}
```

where the result is

```
{{0,0},{0,2},{1,1},{1,0},{2,1},{3,0},{3,0}}
```

where the 'x' components of the list remained the same, but those that were not members of the sublist had their 'y' components changed to zero.

Comment: I think you're almost there; the problem is that you're using `->` instead of `:>`, so `x` is treated as a symbol and not bound by the lhs. But even if you fix that `/.` would attempt the rule on every part of the expression, even ones like the whole list itself, which also match the pattern. Use a more specific pattern: `shortlist /. {x_, y_} /; !MemberQ[sublist, {x,y}] :> {x,0}` If you have nesting issues, and want to make sure to only do the replacement on e.g. the first level, use `Replace` with a level specification: `Replace[shortlist, {x_, y_} /; !MemberQ[sublist, {x,y}] :> {x,0}, {1}]`

Comment: My hero, thank you so much. I always have issues with these kinds of symbolic heavy functions in Mathematica. I really appreciate the detailed explanation.